# Show $f$ is not $1-1$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R$ be a continuously differentiable function. Show that $f$ is not $1-1$.

I know I will need to use the Inverse Function Theorem and consider some open set A with $g:A\to \Bbb R^2$ defined by $g(x,y)=\big(f(x,y),y\big)$.

Answer (score 5):

Being continuous, $f$ assumes its min and max on the compact $S^1$. By the IVT, any value between min and max ias assumed once in each of the two arcs bounded by a minimal and a maximal point.

Comment: In other words, there is already no continuos 1-1 map $S^1\to\mathbb R$.

Comment: I'm really trying to understand this answer, but I just can't.  What do you mean "by the intermediate value theorem, any value between min and max is assumed once in each of the two arcs bounded by a minimal and maximal point"?

Comment: @user46944, pick two distinct paths from the point at which minimum is achieved to the point at which the maximum is achieved. on both paths, there is one point each, at least, has the same intermediate value(average of the max and min). so the function $f$ cannot be $1$-$1$.

Comment: @abel So basically, assuming the function is not constant, there are two points on the circle -- one for the minimum and one for the maximum.  But if you consider the circle as the union of the two arcs formed between the points, then on each arc, by the intermediate value theorem, there is a value from the arc such that its image equals the "average" of the arc -- but both arcs have the same "average", so the two distinct points (one from each arc) are being mapped to the same point.  Is that right?

Comment: @user46944  yes. i just picked the average just to be concrete. you could pick any value between the max and the min.

Comment: @abel I understand now.  Thank you for explaining it.

Comment: @user46944, you are welcome.

Comment: Where continuously differentiable applied here. Any continuous function on a compact set is uniformly continuous and hence will attain its maxima and minima...?

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought this was a more general result:

No function defined on a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be 1-1, basically by the pigeonhole principle.

The nonexistence of a utility function representing lexicographic preferences basically boils down to this principle.

Comment: No idea what you're talking about; the pigeon-hole principle is usually reserved for finite sets. Also you definitely need to add something to "compact subset of $\mathbb R^2$", because, for example, $[0,1]$ can be embedded into $\mathbb R^2$, and there's definitely a 1-1 function $[0,1] \to \mathbb R$.

Comment: *nondegenerate subset / full-rank subset; better?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by nondegenerate or full rank with respect to compact subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ (both of these terms do have precise meanings in other contexts that I'm well aware of). Hagaon von Eitzen's answer demonstrates that any subset $C \subset \mathbb R^2$ that contains a copy of $S^1$ cannot have a 1-1 function $C \to \mathbb R$, so, for example, any $C$ which contains an open disk has no 1-1 function. This sounds like it could be what you mean by full rank? I still don't know what you mean by the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: @DustanLevenstein *cannot have a 1-1 **continuous** function $C \to \Bbb R$

Comment: Yes, inclusion of an open disk is equivalent to what I have in mind--basically any subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ in disguise. And maybe pigeonhole isn't the right word--but it basically comes down to the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is larger than that of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @user46944 yes, of course, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelChirico The cardinality of $\mathbb R^2$ is exactly the same as the cardinality of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @MichaelChirico As Dustan noted, as *sets*, $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ has the same number of elements as $\mathbb{R}$.  As vector spaces, however, $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ is "larger" than $\Bbb R$ in that the former has dimension $2$ (i.e., 2 basis elements) and the latter has dimension $1$ (i.e., 1 basis element).  So you can't find an isomorphism between the two because there is no way to bijectively map 2 basis elements onto 1 basis element.  Is this what you are talking about?

Comment: I'm gonna migrate this to a new question as it appears I've misunderstood a proof for some time. In the meantime, can you give me an example of a 1-1 DIS-continuous function from $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm writing up a new question about this now.. this has gone off the rails haha

Comment: Here's the question: [link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1145650/reconciling-two-results-about-1-1-functions-on-mathbbr2). The point is $(\frac{1}{3}(e^3-e^2+1),\frac{1}{3})$.

Comment: I don't understand why all of the comments were deleted without notice.  I wanted to reference those functions... Is "silent moderation" really appropriate for this site?

Comment: a simple reason why your functions failed is because they were continuously differentiable on a compact set--say, $[\frac{1}{3},\frac{2}{3}]^2$. The level sets are invertible there...