# Reconciling two results about 1-1 functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I'm having trouble with my understanding of a well-established result--my take on the intuition behind it has been undermined by a question asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1142138/show-f-is-not-1-1/1142189).

The result is from economics, about the nonexistence of a utility function representing lexicographic preferences over two goods. Preferences are lexicographic if you evaluate bundles (comparing, say, $(x,y)$ and $(x',y')$) in order: first, you compare $x$ and $x'$. If (WLOG) $x'>x$, you prefer the latter bundle, regardless of $y$ and $y'$. Only if $x=x'$ do you compare $y$ and $y'$, in which case you prefer the bundle with more $y$.

(This is like looking up words in a dictionary--the second letter only matters if the first letters are the same.)

This is covered concisely in the first 16 pages of Ariel Rubensteins lecture notes [here](http://press.princeton.edu/rubinstein/lecture2.pdf)--pages 15 & 16 cover the proof, and the lead-up to that the notation required to understand the proof.

My take on the intuition has always been that it's impossible because there are no 1-1 functions defined on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, and by extension on $\mathbb{R}^2$--continuous or otherwise. In turn this is because there are "not enough bins" in one dimension to handle both dimensions being mapped into $\mathbb{R}$--as mentioned in the post, this reasoning is a hybrid of the intuition of the pigeonhole principle and countability arguments.

Packing on the economics terminology, the indifference sets for these preferences are singletons--the individual is only equally happy if two bundles are exactly identical (whereas we typically assign tradeoffs--willingness to sacrifice some $x$ to get more $y$--so getting a 1-1 function on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ is basically the same as finding a function to represent the preferences.

This reasoning has been called into question by the above-referenced SE Math topic, wherein it's been suggested that it's only *continuous* functions which are prevented from being 1-1. But the proof about lexicographic preferences has nothing to do with continuity--instead relying on the density of the reals.

Hopefully I explained the background well enough for someone to help me understand--why do we need the function on $[0,1]\times[0,1]$ to be continuous to guarantee it's not bijective? Or is there something else about the setup of the lexicographic proof that keeps the two ideas separate?

PS I'm not sure how to tag this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question you refer to talks about functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ while the notes talk about maps $[0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{Q}$. The difference is in the codomain. $\mathbb{Q}$ has lower cardinality than $\mathbb{R}^2$, but $\mathbb{R}$ does not.

An example of a one-to-one function $[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$: map the element $(a,b) \in [0,1]^2$, where the coordinates have decimal representations $a = 0.a_1 a_2 a_3 \ldots$ and $b = 0.b_1 b_2 b_3 \ldots$ to the element $0.a_1 b_1 a_2 b_2 a_3 b_3 \ldots$. We can get around issues with non-unique decimal representations (repeating $9$s) by specifying a decimal representation for every $x \in [0,1]$ beforehand.

--

The key point in the proof about utility representations uses the extra condition that $u(x) \geq u(y)$ if $x$ is lexicographically larger than $y$. This condition guarantees that $q:[0,1] \to \mathbb{Q}$ is strictly increasing, and hence one-to-one. If we try to imitate the same proof for an arbitrary one-to-one function $[0,1]^2 \to [0,1]$ the map $q$ will not be one-to-one.

Comment: That's not defined at $(1,b)$ or $(a,1)$.

Comment: Also, the codomain in both cases is $\mathbb{R}$. See page 2: _the function_ $U:X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ldots$

Comment: Yes, just write $a=a_0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$, same for $b$, and map to $0.a_0 b_0 a_1 b_1\ldots$

Comment: That function's not continuous?

Comment: No it's not continuous. In the economics notes, the part where a cardinality argument is used, in the proof on page 16, it is about a function $q: [0,1]^2 \to \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Fair enough. I'm still not wrapping my head around why one works and the other doesn't--why can we reduce the lexicographic question down to a map into $\mathbb{Q}$, but can't in general? What exactly in the setup of the lexicographic preferences buys that?

Comment: Check the edit.

Comment: I'm going to let the dust settle for a little--seems subtle. Sounds like we would have to do something like map $(a,b)$ to $0.a_0 a_1 a_2 \ldots b_0 b_1 b_2 \ldots$ to keep lexicography...

Comment: side not: I'm not sure I see that this function's discontinuous--any simple way to see that? I'm thinking if we want mappings within $10^{-n}$, just keep the original points within, say, $10^{-100n}$ of each other...

Comment: $(0.5,0)$ is mapped to $0.5$ and there are arbitrarily close points of the form $(0.49a_3 a_4 \ldots,0)$ that are mapped to $0.4090a_3 \ldots$.

Comment: We should be able, then, to construct a representation on $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\times[0,1]$. But I'm not sure how to do so rigorously; if we can number the rationals in increasing order (feels problematic) $q_1<\cdots<q_n<\cdots$, we can map $(q_n,y)$ to $\frac{b_n}{a_n}y$, where $a_n=b_{n-1}+\frac{1}{n^2}, b_n=b_{n-1}+\frac{2}{n^2}, a_1=0, b_1=1$ (basically lines of decreasing slopes with limits approaching $\frac{\pi^2}{3}-1$. But the crux is the ordering, which feels taboo.

Comment: @MichaelChirico It feels problematic because it is.  You can't enumerate the rationals in such a way.  Sure, there is a smallest rational in $\Bbb Q \cap [0,1]$, namely, $0$.  But there is no immediate successor to $0$ in this set.  So if $q_{0} = 0$, you can't find $q_{1}$ such that $q_{0} < q_{1} < q$ for all other $q$.  Specifically, $(q_{0} + q_{1})/2$ will be a rational number strictly between $q_{0}$ and any $q_{1}$ you choose.

Comment: Of course. Does this mean the nonrepresentation continues for bundles in $\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]\times[0,1]$? Or just that I've taken a poor guess at defining the function.